# Avoiding use of "this" in constructors

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I am looking for this kind of result:

```
var Dog = function() {
  this.tail = 1;
  var tail = this.tail;
  this.print = function() {
    console.log(tail);
  };
};
```

Where I use

```
tail = this.tail;
```

to avoid the use of the **this** keyword in the print function body. However this method seems sort of hacky and I feel like their must be a better/more standard/different way to do this kind of thing.

The reason I wish to do this is because I need to convert some code which was previously all global variables and functions into an object contructor, and prefixing all variables with the **this** keyword will be a lot of work, and will make the code a lot uglier.

Any insight is useful, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: You could use a closure instead. But it would hide all the variables from being accessed outside of the object.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I don't think a closure would help in this situation. @4castle

Comment: "and will make the code a lot uglier." --- it will not.

Comment: why do you use `console.log(dog);` ? Shouldn't this be `console.log(this);`?

Comment: @Aloso this will refer the global scope (window) due to it being in a function...

Comment: Use `var` (or similar) to declare variables!!!

Comment: @ElliotE you can also do function.bind too, so you can keep using "this" https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: @Aloso you are right it shouldn't be dog, it should be tail, I've edited my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Oriol what if I need to be able to reference the instance variables like: (new Dog).tail; I can't do that if I use var.

Comment: Now I understand why you are doing this! I think Oriol meant you should write `var tail = this.tail` instead of `tail = this.tail`. I agree it's better.

Comment: @Aloso Ah I see I think you are right! However my problem is still unsolved.

Comment: If the constant references to `this` are driving you up the wall you might want to try [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org). It's unavoidable in JavaScript unless you use a meta-JavaScript-like language. [`@tail` is equivalent to `this.tail`](https://coffeescript-cookbook.github.io/chapters/classes_and_objects/class-variables-and-instance-variables). The more you do JavaScript, the less `this` should bug you. It's like complaining about how "the" appears so often in English.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following? I tested it, it works ;)

```
var Dog = function() {
    this.tail = 1;
    this.print = function() {
        console.log(this.tail);
    };
};
```

or

```
var Dog = function() {
    var tail = 1;
    this.print = function() {
        console.log(tail);
    };
};
```

There's just one difference: `this.tail` can be edited from the global scope, `var tail` can't. But I don't think that this is a problem in this case.

**EDIT: Access tail without `this`**

```
var Dog = function() {
    var tail = 1;
    this.getTail = function() {
        return tail;
    };
    this.setTail = function(newTail) {
        tail = newTail;
    };

    this.print = function() {
        console.log(tail);
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Aloso. Unfortunately your first example is exactly what I am trying to avoid. Because I have a lot of variables in my functions I want to avoid having to prefix the instance variables with **this**. 

In your second example tail cannot be referenced as such: `(new Dog).tail;` which is necessary.

Comment: There are only these two ways, you have to decide. Mixing them up is always unsatisfying because then you have two variables for the same purpose that can have different values.

Comment: In the second example there is a way to acess tail, by defining a getter and setter method (or just one of them, how you want)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this.  However, you will have to create a private variable and then expose it through a public property by using [object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).  You do have to be aware of browser [compatibility issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Browser_compatibility) with this.  For example object.defineProperty was not supported until IE9.

Example:

```js
var log = function(message) {
  $('#log').append('<div>' + message + '</div>');
}

var Dog = function(aNumber) {
  //Create private variable for tail.  
  var tail = aNumber;

  //Create public property for tail.
  //BTW, it is generally bad practice to name a property the same name as a private variable.
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'tail', {
    get: function() {
      return tail;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      tail = value;
    }
  });

  log('ctor tail:' + tail);
  log('ctor this.tail:' + this.tail);

  this.print = function() {
    log('print tail :' + tail);
    log('print this.tail :' + this.tail)
  };
};

var firstDog = new Dog(1);
var secondDog = new Dog(2);

firstDog.tail = 3;
secondDog.tail = 4;

firstDog.print();
secondDog.print();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='log' />
```

In your original question you referenced tail in global scope.  Example:

```
tail = this.tail;
```

In this case if you instantiate multiple instances of Dog, each instance will reference the same version of tail which will be different than this.tail.

Example:

```js
var log = function(message) {
  $('#log').append('<div>' + message + '</div>');
}

var Dog = function(aNumber) {
  this.tail = aNumber;
  //Because tail hasn't been declared your referring to tail in global scope.  This is bad! 
  tail = this.tail;
  log('ctor tail:' + tail);
  log('ctor this.tail:' + this.tail);
  this.print = function() {
      log('print tail:' + tail);
      log('print this.tail:' + this.tail);
  };
};

var firstDog = new Dog(1);
var secondDog = new Dog(2);
firstDog.print(); //tail is 2 when you want it to be 1
secondDog.print();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='log' />
```

In your update you declared tail like so:

```
var tail = this.tail;
```

This does create a private variable scoped the constructor of Dog.  However, this will lead to inconsistent results as tail and this.tail will maintain different values.

Example:

```js
var log = function(message) {
  $('#log').append('<div>' + message + '</div>');
}

var Dog = function(aNumber) {
  this.tail = aNumber;
  //Now you have tail scoped to this constructor/closure.  However, this.tail and tail will reference different variables.
  var tail = this.tail;
  log('ctor tail:' + tail);
  log('ctor this.tail:' + this.tail);
  this.print = function() {
    log('print tail :' + tail);
    log('print this.tail :' + this.tail);
  };
};

var firstDog = new Dog(1);
var secondDog = new Dog(2);

firstDog.tail = 3;
secondDog.tail = 4;

firstDog.print();
secondDog.print();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='log' />
```

If you cannot use object.defineProperty for what ever reason, you are stuck with prefixing your variables with this. However, to make sure it's 100% safe you will want to alias `this` in your constructor.

Example:

```js
var log = function(message) {
  $('#log').append('<div>' + message + '</div>');
}

var Dog = function(aNumber) {
  var self = this
  self.tail = aNumber;
  log('ctor self.tail:' + this.tail);
  this.print = function() {
    log('print self.tail :' + self.tail);
  };
};

var firstDog = new Dog(1);
var secondDog = new Dog(2);

firstDog.tail = 3;
secondDog.tail = 4;

firstDog.print();
secondDog.print();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='log' />
```

Btw, John Resig put together a great [resource](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/) to better understand JavaScript including variable scoping.  I highly recommend going though that.